# How to use the pedometer plugin?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

i'm a working on a projet based on native application. I have to code a simple pedometer in cordova. I've downloaded the plugin in my file and i don't succed to get all the informations back
Here is my code :

```js
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },
    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    }
};

app.initialize();
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
        <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <title>Pedometer</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="app">
            <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
            <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
                <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
                <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script>
        var successHandler = function (pedometerData) {
    // pedometerData.numberOfSteps;
    // pedometerData.distance;
    // pedometerData.floorsAscended;
    // pedometerData.floorsDescended;
};
         pedometer.startPedometerUpdates(successHandler, onError);
 
         pedometer.stopPedometerUpdates(successCallback, failureCallback);
 
 
 
 
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for your help ! ;)

Comment: I don't see how or where `pedometer` is defined. Could you post some code to a JS fiddle or similar?

Comment: i don't know how to attribute this kind of script to my html code. If someone just can help me to begin ...

Comment: because it came from a plugin pedometer

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/uk.co.ilee.pedometer):

> **Platform and device support**
>
> iOS 8+ only. These capabilities are not supported on all devices, even
>   with iOS 8, so please ensure you use the *check feature support*
>   functions.

So, you can test if the feature is supported with this code:

```
pedometer.isStepCountingAvailable(function(){
    console.log( "Pedometer step counting is available" );
}, function(){
    console.log( "Pedometer step counting is NOT available" );
});
```

and then you can do the same thing with `pedometer.isDistanceAvailable()` and `pedometer.isFloorCountingAvailable`

Comment: but it said connection to device when i launch ripple :/

Comment: it says 'connecting to device' and 'device ready' in your HTML but it is not bound to a pedometer.  It changes when the (mobile) device is has loaded the DOM (i.e. in 'ready' state)

Comment: but when i click on the index.html , the function  document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    }, must turn on True right ?

Comment: I see no evidence of that.  What makes you believe so?  According to the docs (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) if you use `false`, you are not indicating you want `userCapture`.  Perhaps you meant to put `true`?